# T-SQL: Is there a way to check if the value of one variable is present in another variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, variables

Code:

```
Declare @a VARCHAR(100) = ';2;9;12;13;14;16;17;21;'
Declare @b VARCHAR(100) = ';2;12;13;'
Declare @c VARCHAR(100)
While len(@a) > 1
Begin
    Set @c = substring(@a,1,charindex(';',@a,2))
    Set @b += @c Where @c Not In @b  ----This statement gives a problem and shows a syntax error
    Set @a = substring(@a,charindex(';',@a,2),len(@a))
    Select @a, @b, @c
End
```

What I'm trying to accomplish here is that I have declared 2 variables of VARCHAR type and assigned them some value. A third variable I've declared is a sub-string derived from the 1st variable. The value of the 3rd variable I'm trying to find it's presence in the 2nd variable and if it's not I'm trying to concatenate it with the 2nd one.

So the first value that @c would get is: ';2;' and it should compare with @b and if not present in @b it should concatenate with @b.

So basically the result should look something like this in the end.

**@b = ';2;12;13;9;14;16;17;21;'**

Kindly help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem straightforwardly, change:

```
Set @b += @c Where @c Not In @b
```

To:

```
SET @b += CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(@c, @b) > 0 THEN '' ELSE @c END
```

Comment: ah sorry, think i got the case statement the wrong way, try the updated answer.

Comment: This works..Thanks. I just need a way now to trim the extra semicolons

Comment: Used this : Set @b += CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(@c, @b) > 0 THEN '' ELSE substring(@c,2,len(@c)) END

Comment: No probs, nice, glad it helped

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, I believe you would want to use sets (tables) instead of strings.  You could do this with strings if absolutely necessary using a split function (exists in SQL Server 2016 but will have to write your own for prior versions.  There are tons of examples on S.O.)

To use sets, Try this:

```
DECLARE @a TABLE (id INT identity(1, 1), val INT)
DECLARE @b TABLE (Val INT)
DECLARE @c INT
DECLARE @aSetStr VARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @bSetStr VARCHAR(max)

INSERT INTO @a
VALUES (2), (9), (12), (13), (14), (16), (17), (21)

INSERT INTO @b
VALUES (2), (12), (13)

DECLARE @i INT = 0

WHILE EXISTS (
        SELECT A.id
        FROM @a A
        LEFT JOIN @b B
            ON A.Val = B.Val
        WHERE A.id > @i AND B.Val IS NULL
        )
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @i = A.id, @c = A.Val
    FROM @a A
    LEFT JOIN @b B
        ON A.Val = B.Val
    WHERE A.id > @i AND B.Val IS NULL
    ORDER BY A.id ASC

    IF NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM @b B
            WHERE B.Val = @c
            )
        INSERT INTO @b (Val)
        SELECT @c

    SELECT @aSetStr = STUFF((
                SELECT ';' + CAST(val AS VARCHAR(max))
                FROM @a
                FOR XML PATH('')
                ), 1, 0, '') + ';'

    SELECT @bSetStr = STUFF((
                SELECT ';' + CAST(val AS VARCHAR(max))
                FROM @b
                FOR XML PATH('')
                ), 1, 0, '') + ';'

    SELECT @aSetStr AS [Set A], @bSetStr AS [Set B], cast(@C AS VARCHAR(255)) AS [Value of C]
END
```

This will Yield

```
Set A                      Set B                     Value of C
-------------------------- ------------------------- ------------
;2;9;12;13;14;16;17;21;    ;2;12;13;9;               9

Set A                      Set B                     Value of C
-------------------------- ------------------------- ------------
;2;9;12;13;14;16;17;21;    ;2;12;13;9;14;            14

Set A                      Set B                     Value of C
-------------------------- ------------------------- ------------
;2;9;12;13;14;16;17;21;    ;2;12;13;9;14;16;         16

Set A                      Set B                     Value of C
-------------------------- ------------------------- ------------
;2;9;12;13;14;16;17;21;    ;2;12;13;9;14;16;17;      17

Set A                      Set B                     Value of C
-------------------------- ------------------------- ------------
;2;9;12;13;14;16;17;21;    ;2;12;13;9;14;16;17;21;   21
```

Comment: Thanks @Jay for the answer. The code I'm using is actually working. There's just a problem with the value comparison statement: "SET b += c Where c Not In b".  And Split function I've already created since I'm using SQL Server 2012. So In my current code only the value of B doesn't get updated apart from that I'm getting the results of A and C

Comment: It's not allowing me to use @ sign before the variables since they are not user names

Comment: So in actual fact...... your code is not working? I suggest you read this answer and learn something.

Comment: here is your issue: Set @b += @c Where @c Not In @b...  This would need to change to Select @B += @c + ';' where not exists (Select 1 from fnSplit(@b,';') x where x.SplitItemValue = @c)

Comment: Thanks @JayWheeler, but I don't have a particular function for splitting, I'm using a while loop for doing regressive splitting here

Answer (score 1):

```
TRY THIS CODE
    Declare @a VARCHAR(100) = ';2;9;12;13;14;16;17;21;'
    Declare @b VARCHAR(100) = ';2;12;13;'
    Declare @c VARCHAR(100)
    While len(@a) > 1
    Begin
        Set @c = substring(@a,1,charindex(';',@a,2))
            IF (@c) NOT IN (@b) begin
                Set @b += @c
            end

         Set @a = substring(@a,charindex(';',@a,2),len(@a))
        Select @a, @b, replace(@c,';','')
    End
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried this a number of times, it doesn't actually run the IF statement, just simply concatenates the value of c to b

Answer (score 1):

Another way of getting expected Result

```
Declare @a VARCHAR(100) = ';2;9;12;13;14;16;17;21;'
Declare @b VARCHAR(100) = ';2;12;13;'

DECLARE @Tempa TABLE (Value nvarchar(1000))
INSERT INTO @Tempa VALUES(@a)
DECLARE @Tempb TABLE (Value nvarchar(1000))
INSERT INTO @Tempb VALUES(@b)

;WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT Cast(dataa AS INT) AS DataA 
         FROM   (SELECT split.a.value('.', 'nvarchar(1000)') AS DataA 
                 FROM   (SELECT Cast('<S>' + Replace(value, ';', '</S><S>') + 
                                     '</S>' 
                                     AS 
                                     XML) AS 
                                Data 
                         FROM   @Tempa)AS A 
                        CROSS apply data.nodes('S') AS Split(a)) dt 
         WHERE  dt.dataa <> '' 
         UNION 
         SELECT Cast(dataa AS INT) AS DataA 
         FROM   (SELECT split.a.value('.', 'nvarchar(1000)') AS DataA 
                 FROM   (SELECT Cast('<S>' + Replace(value, ';', '</S><S>') + 
                                     '</S>' 
                                     AS 
                                     XML) AS 
                                Data 
                         FROM   @Tempb)AS A 
                        CROSS apply data.nodes('S') AS Split(a))dt 
         WHERE  dt.dataa <> '') 
SELECT ''';' + Stuff((SELECT '; '+Cast(dataa AS VARCHAR(10)) FROM cte ORDER BY 
       dataa 
       FOR xml path ('')), 1, 1, '') + ' ;''' AS ExpectedCResult
```

Result

```
ExpectedCResult
---------------------------------
'; 2; 9; 12; 13; 14; 16; 17; 21 ;'
```

Answer (score 1):

If your values are unique, you can use `UNION` to merge your strings:

```
    Declare @a VARCHAR(100) = ';2;9;12;13;14;16;17;21;'
    Declare @b VARCHAR(100) = ';2;7;12;13;'
    Declare @c VARCHAR(100)

    ;WITH 
    a AS
    (
        SELECT @a AS FIELD, SUBSTRING(@a, 1, CHARINDEX(';', @a)) AS num
        UNION ALL
        SELECT RIGHT(FIELD, LEN(FIELD)-LEN(num)), SUBSTRING(RIGHT(FIELD, LEN(FIELD)-LEN(num)), 1, CHARINDEX(';', RIGHT(FIELD, LEN(FIELD)-LEN(num))))
        FROM a
        WHERE FIELD != num
    ),
    b AS
    (
        SELECT @b AS FIELD, SUBSTRING(@b, 1, CHARINDEX(';', @b)) AS num
        UNION ALL
        SELECT RIGHT(FIELD, LEN(FIELD)-LEN(num)), SUBSTRING(RIGHT(FIELD, LEN(FIELD)-LEN(num)), 1, CHARINDEX(';', RIGHT(FIELD, LEN(FIELD)-LEN(num))))
        FROM b
        WHERE FIELD != num
    )
    SELECT @c = 
        (
        SELECT ';' + CAST(v.num AS VARCHAR)
        FROM (
            SELECT CAST(REPLACE(a.num, ';', '') AS INT) num
            FROM a
            WHERE a.num != ';'
            UNION 
            SELECT CAST(REPLACE(b.num, ';', '') AS INT)
            FROM b
            WHERE b.num != ';'
        ) v
        FOR XML PATH('')
        ) + ';'

SELECT @c
```

Comment: Thanks @DenisRubashkin for the answer